# React embedded cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a object list with few elements, single element looks like:

```
{
    'id': '5d4647dsa54d6s4ad65as',
    'date': '2016-06-09T15:03:12.000Z',
    'title': 'Istvan 5',
    'text': 'Pathos, betrayal, "The Galaxy will be Burning!", ',
    'coments': [
        {
            'id': 'qwerty',
            'user': 'Gu1iman',
            'text': 'The Code of Adeptus Astartes does not approve of     this'
        },
        {
            'id': 'asdfg',
            'user': 'Feru5 Manu5',
            'text': 'I lost my had for love!'
        },
        {
            'id': 'zxcvb',
            'user': 'Fu1grim Fenix',
            'text': 'I know bro, I know'
        },
    ]
},
```

I can display text:

```
export default class ArticleList extends PureComponent
  {
   state = {
       openArticleId: null
   }
   render(){
       const articleElements = this.props.articles.map((articles,    index)     =>
           <li key={articles.id} className='article-list__li' onClick=              
  {this.handelClick.bind(this, articles.id)}>
               <Article article = {articles}
                        isOpen = {this.state.openArticleId ===    articles.id}
                        onButtonClick = {this.handelClick.bind(this, articles.id)}/>
           </li>
       )
       return (
           <ul>
               {articleElements}
           </ul>
       )
   }
   handelClick = openArticleId => this.setState({
       openArticleId: this.state.openArticleId === openArticleId ?    null : openArticleId
   })
}
```

But I don't mind how display 'comments' for this text. How can I display this? I've tried to write embedded cycle, but it not worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`<Article article = {articles}` - use data you're already passing:

```
this.props.article.comments.map(
```

inside render of `<Article />` of course. Result will be rendered inside `<li />` tag. And of course you can render comments only for 'open' article using `isOpen` prop:

```
(!!this.props.isOpen && this.props.article.comments.map(
```